# Apply css on condition?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a total noob in css... I am using nav-tabs in bootstrap library to list some items, however, I have two lists, one i would like to change the background color and the other one i want to keep it with the original color, so in order to change the background color i use:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;  
}
```

but the changes are obviously general, how can i specify to which list they should apply?

PS: this is the list i actually want to change the background once it is active.

```
<ul id="glossaryTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li><a href="#video" data-toggle="tab">video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#audio" data-toggle="tab">audio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foreign_version" data-toggle="tab">foreign version</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use the id to distinguish between the two and apply on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of applying the CSS styling to `.nav-tabs`, you just use the element ID:

```
#glossaryTab > li.active > a,
#glossaryTab > li.active > a:hover,
#glossaryTab > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;  
}
```

Comment: perfect Thanks a lot to both you @aaroncatlin and @ putvande, in 10mins i will be able to accept the answer

Comment: Note that using the `a`-tag alone will apply to all links: `a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover, a:focus`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#glossaryTab .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
#glossaryTab.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
       color: #fff;
       background-color: #bfbfbf;  
}
```

Comment: You have a slight mistake in your CSS rule. The space between `#glossaryTab .nav-tabs` is too much. You're selecting `.nav-tabs` as a child of `#glossaryTab`.